# Are there any jQuery plugins to make form elements on any computer look like mac form elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there is one to turn scroll windows to look like they do on a mac (the middle one):

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/examples.html

But are there any plugins that works on form elements (selects, radio, checkboxes, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use [jQTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/). You can then make the graphics look just like the Mac ones and you'll all be set.

Comment: It may take a bit of work creating the graphics but the javascript portion will all be there and working. I have used the plugin before and I can tell you that it'll work in all browsers.